# Objectives Global to System

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have a question about ***Objectives Global to System*** attribute of *organization* element. What does 'Objectives Global to System' mean? What is its usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Objectives Global to System`, which is set to true by default, means that all global objectives are available for all courses taken by the same learner for a certain attempt. Let say you set the objective satisfied status of "OBJ_1" to true in course A, this value will be available to that learner if he took course B in the same LMS.

Comment: what does _for a certain attempt_ mean @FadelMS?

Comment: If the learner attempts course A (in the previous example) to the second time, the values of the the global objectives will be set to the default.

Comment: In the previous example, if the learner takes course A and after experience he triggers an Exit All navigation request. In this case, should global objectives of course A be set to the default before the learner takes course A again?